# Subflow screens showing parent flow header

Tags: visual-workflow, screen-flow

I have two flows, one flow i basically a decision that goes into different subflows.

When you hit the subflow i want it to show that specific header so the user has context to what they're doing....instead it shows the parent flows header. Other than Text output is there any other work around for this?

Comment: From my understanding, not without using either a custom component or as you say some text output component. It's because the sub-flows are running in the context of the parent flow, which is what is being displayed regardless of whatever subflow might be called during running of the flow.